# Windows Server 2008 R2 Stand Alone Certificate Authority - creating a new root certificate

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2008-r2, ssl-certificate

I seemed to have hosed up my Certificate Authority.

I have a Stand Alone Certificate Authority and it's not on a domain or enterprise so there's no certificate templates. Currently all of the applications that are using SSL are dev environments and all on an internal network of about 15 computers. A while back while I was freshly hired and very green to everything the original certificate expired. When I download a renewed certificate from certsrv the certificate gives a "common name invalid" error which could be contributed to recent network changes.

So right now I need to figure out how to create a new certificate with the correct common name that I can download from certsrv. If there's any information I left out please let me know.

Comment: The common name should be the fully qualified domain name but my predecessor that set up the CA only put an abbreviated name.

Comment: Well....I've narrowed it down to the Subject Alternative Name not being set in the certificate. Which is a recent Chrome/FireFox update.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've done as far as the request is concerned. The guide that I followed was this: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzHtJ33cIng

What I'm not sure what to do after is how do I get this request to generate a certificate that the users can access through certsrv?

Comment: On the CA, run `certreq.exe <file>` to submit the request to the CA. By `certsrv` do you mean the deprecated web enrolment front-end?

Comment: Yeah...is it deprecated in 2008 R2? That's what I'm limited to because my IT manager doesn't want to upgrade yet. What replaced it? How do client computers download the SSL certificate from a CA?

Comment: As it's an standalone CA you have to export the certificate as a file and pass that (file share or email etc.) to the client.  The Microsoft way to do this is to have an enterprise CA which can do all of this automatically over the network.  As you only have 15 subscribers, maybe it's time to redesign your PKI?

Comment: Do you have any information that I can read on how to redesign it?

Comment: No - https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic - request for reading/learning info isn't on-topic here.

Comment: Alright....so with my 2008 R2 setup I just have to create a custom request by the youtube link I posted earlier and then complete the request on my CA and distribute the certificate. Also add it to the bindings in IIS. Did I miss anything?

Comment: That sums it up, yes.